# Python: Easy PC to PC communcation

Tags: python, string, tcp, udp

I am interested in making an application that will transmit strings from one computer to another. I am interested in TCP or UDP communication. I have implemented UDP but it seems to be able to send up to 512 bytes of data / packet. Implementing packet splitting and joining at both ends should be a pain in the ass, so I was wondering if there's a library or anything like this to allow me to transmit a long string (No more than 10-20 KB hopefully, usually around 1-2KB) directly to the other computer. I don't care about encrypted communication since no sensitive data is sent/retrieved. Any suggestions I could use?

Here's what I am thinking of right now:

```
import easylib
def receivedData(text):
     print(text)
sendData("Hello world! Oh my gosh, this is a pretty long string. Good to know I can send it without any problems.")
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Nice small example](http://www.doughellmann.com/PyMOTW/socket/tcp.html) of Python socket server.
Also you can user some more higher level protocols, [like XMLRPC](http://docs.python.org/2/library/simplexmlrpcserver.html)

Comment: Was just about to recommend XMLRPC.  It's simple and effective.

Comment: Thanks! You both won a free license for my software. But it's free anyways. :P